# Unity - AlphaToMask in shader doesn't seem to be working on mobile (transparency)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, shader, transparency

I found this shader online that mimics liquid movement in a container.

Here it is (https://pastebin.com/wRWnHQH2)

```
    Shader "Unlit/SpecialFX/Liquid"
 {
    Properties
    {
        _Tint ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _FillAmount ("Fill Amount", Range(-10,10)) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _WobbleX ("WobbleX", Range(-1,1)) = 0.0
        [HideInInspector] _WobbleZ ("WobbleZ", Range(-1,1)) = 0.0
        _TopColor ("Top Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _FoamColor ("Foam Line Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Rim ("Foam Line Width", Range(0,0.1)) = 0.0    
        _RimColor ("Rim Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _RimPower ("Rim Power", Range(0,10)) = 0.0
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Geometry"  "DisableBatching" = "True" }

                Pass
        {
         Zwrite On
         Cull Off // we want the front and back faces
         AlphaToMask On // transparency

         CGPROGRAM


         #pragma vertex vert
         #pragma fragment frag
         // make fog work
         #pragma multi_compile_fog

         #include "UnityCG.cginc"

         struct appdata
         {
           float4 vertex : POSITION;
           float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
           float3 normal : NORMAL; 
         };

         struct v2f
         {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float3 viewDir : COLOR;
            float3 normal : COLOR2;    
            float fillEdge : TEXCOORD2;
         };

         sampler2D _MainTex;
         float4 _MainTex_ST;
         float _FillAmount, _WobbleX, _WobbleZ;
         float4 _TopColor, _RimColor, _FoamColor, _Tint;
         float _Rim, _RimPower;

         float4 RotateAroundYInDegrees (float4 vertex, float degrees)
         {
            float alpha = degrees * UNITY_PI / 180;
            float sina, cosa;
            sincos(alpha, sina, cosa);
            float2x2 m = float2x2(cosa, sina, -sina, cosa);
            return float4(vertex.yz , mul(m, vertex.xz)).xzyw ;            
         }


         v2f vert (appdata v)
         {
            v2f o;

            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
            UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);        
            // get world position of the vertex
            float3 worldPos = mul (unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex.xyz);  
            // rotate it around XY
            float3 worldPosX= RotateAroundYInDegrees(float4(worldPos,0),360);
            // rotate around XZ
            float3 worldPosZ = float3 (worldPosX.y, worldPosX.z, worldPosX.x);     
            // combine rotations with worldPos, based on sine wave from script
            float3 worldPosAdjusted = worldPos + (worldPosX  * _WobbleX)+ (worldPosZ* _WobbleZ);
            // how high up the liquid is
            o.fillEdge =  worldPosAdjusted.y + _FillAmount;

            o.viewDir = normalize(ObjSpaceViewDir(v.vertex));
            o.normal = v.normal;
            return o;
         }

         fixed4 frag (v2f i, fixed facing : VFACE) : SV_Target
         {
           // sample the texture
           fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Tint;
           // apply fog
           UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);

           // rim light
           float dotProduct = 1 - pow(dot(i.normal, i.viewDir), _RimPower);
           float4 RimResult = smoothstep(0.5, 1.0, dotProduct);
           RimResult *= _RimColor;

           // foam edge
           float4 foam = ( step(i.fillEdge, 0.5) - step(i.fillEdge, (0.5 - _Rim)))  ;
           float4 foamColored = foam * (_FoamColor * 0.9);
           // rest of the liquid
           float4 result = step(i.fillEdge, 0.5) - foam;
           float4 resultColored = result * col;
           // both together, with the texture
           float4 finalResult = resultColored + foamColored;               
           finalResult.rgb += RimResult;

           // color of backfaces/ top
           float4 topColor = _TopColor * (foam + result);
           //VFACE returns positive for front facing, negative for backfacing
           return facing > 0 ? finalResult: topColor;

         }
         ENDCG
        }

    }
}
```

it works nicely except that the AlphaToMask ON  that works on desktop to mask out the fill part doesn't seem to work at all on mobile, showing black instead of transparency.

Any clue on what's going on or how I could solve this?

Comment: Do you get any Warnings (or Errors) when building for mobile? Also, what mobile platform do you use, Android?

Comment: @PhilippLenssen no errors(but not sure about warnings), and yeah building for android!  For now I solved by buying a different asset altho it would've been interesting to know why that didn't work

Answer (score 3):

For those who want it works on mobile devices, just set **AlphaToMask** to **off** (optional), set **Zwrite** to **off** and add line `Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha` below `Zwrite off` line,
also set `"Queue"="Transparent"` or `"AlphaTest"`

```
SubShader
{
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent"  "DisableBatching" = "True" }
    Pass
    {
     Zwrite off
     Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
     Cull Off // we want the front and back faces
     AlphaToMask off CGPROGRAM
     #pragma vertex vert
     #pragma fragment frag
```

([Full code](https://pastebin.com/dQzWDqXh))
([Demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRTRC.jpg))

See also:

Unity Blend Documentation:https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Blend.html

Unity Shader Transparent Tutorial:[Making A Transparent Shader [6/8]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCi4BnnQV2s&feature=emb_logo)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code in your answer. Links to external sites may cease to work in the future, making this answer less useful.

Comment: I'm using this exact code to build to Oculus Quest and unfortunately the answer gives the shader some very strange behaviour - the rear and sides are being drawn over the front - any ideas? @SnightCoder